how to avoid duplicate find of state when updating the state?
here i have code for flutter provider
class Page extends StatelessWidget {
  GlobalState? _state;
  GlobalState get state => _state!;
  set state(GlobalState value) => _state ??= value;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      state = context.read<GlobalState>();
      return Selector<GlobalState, int> (
         selector: (_, innerState) => innerState.intValue,
         builder: (_, value, child) => ...
      );
   }
}

I am sure that the state will be initialized when first built, the next time the program would found that the state is not null and will not assian the context.read<GlobalState>,
but in the Selector, each time when the state notifyListener, the Selector will always looking for the same GlobalState again, how can I improve my code ?
I think that I have located where the GlobalState is, so there is no need to looking for the GlobalState again, I don't know how to fix it in the Provider, or should I turn to getx ?

You should move your state to new class and extends ChangeNotifier. See here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ChangeNotifier-class.html

you mean I can define the state outside, at the global scope, and use the state directly in the widget, right ?
but how can ListenableBuilder replace the Selector ?

This is example use ChangeNotifier with your case. You can divide small Widget and return direct Selector. You can use shouldRebuild in Selector if you don't want to update widget when state changes.
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => Counter()),
      ],
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class Counter with ChangeNotifier {
  int _count = 0;

  int get count => _count;


  /// This function only use when you need change state, 
  /// but doesn't want to re-render all widget that get this state
  // void increment(bool isNotify) {
  //   _count++;
  //   if (isNotify) {
  //     notifyListeners();
  //   }
  // }

  void increment() {
    _count++;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Example'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Selector<Counter, int>(
          builder: (context, data, child) {
            return Container(
              height: 40,
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Center(child: Text('Consumer1: $data')),
            );
          },
          selector: (buildContext, state) {
            return state.count;
          },
          shouldRebuild: (prevState, nextState) {
            //Change logic update widget when state change at here.
            // Return false when widget only get state once time.
            return false;
          }
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        key: const Key('increment_floatingActionButton'),

        /// Calls `context.read` instead of `context.watch` so that it does not rebuild
        /// when [Counter] changes.
        onPressed: () => context.read<Counter>().increment(),
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}


sorry, may be my describtion is not very clear, are you sure that in your code, when state call notifyListeners, the context will not find the Counter again ?
the reason why I use context.read<GlobalState>() is that I want the context just looking for the state only once time

If you only get state once time and don't  want to update someone widget that get state, so you can add condition for call notifyListeners() or use shouldRebuild in Selector. See here: https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/ShouldRebuild.html
